# How to go to the ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have `TableViewController` and `ViewController`. I want to go in `ViewController` after downloading audio. But I go at the moment when audio downloading. I use `fileExists` it check if audio was download. But it doesn’t work. How can I go in after `ViewController` download audio?

This is my code for download and go

```
if (!fileExists) {

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Download audio?" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* actionAdd = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryView = spinner;
        [spinner startAnimating];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39R2Z5RlVWZkN3Vzg";
                NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
                NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        });
        if (fileExists) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];
          }  

    }];
    UIAlertAction* actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    }];

    [alert addAction:actionAdd];
    [alert addAction :actionCancel];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        if (fileExists) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];

        }

    }
```

Comment: add if (fileExists) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];
          }   in your dispatch_async code block

Comment: instead of  `dataWithContentsOfURL ` you should use NSURLSession `downloadTaskWithURL` or `dataTaskWithURL` which will give you delegate method or completion block where you can do the coding you have to do after download complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//**Try This One And Before Set Your Identifier Of ViewController In Inspector **

```
  ViewController *vc17 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

[self presentViewController:vc17 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always execute UI related code in the main queue, like the:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];
```

and you'd better use the NSURLSessionDataTask to download something from web.

Comment: why better use NSURLSessionDataTask?

Comment: because this is the officially recommended way to communicate with the internet, read this:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithResumeData